# Matrix form of STFT

Tags: dft, stft, transform, matrix

IS there a Matrix form of the STFT that could be applied to a signal directly, as in the case of DFT? We know the matrix structure of the DFT Matrix. Can we derive that somehow for a STFT Transform? The parameters that I wish to use are 
N = signal length
R = frame length
overlap = 50%
DFT length = K

Attempt: I have tried to represent the DFT blocks along a diagonal with 50% overlap between the blocks. Each of the DFT Block will be multiplied by a diagonal block of the same size consisting of the window coefficients. Am I heading in the right direction?

Any directions or suggestions would be helpful.
Thanks!!

Comment: Sounds like you're heading in the right direction. Though, usually, the STFT will be there square of the DFT of each frame.

Answer (score 2):

For an overlapped STFT (overlap > 0), the output vector will be larger than the signal input vector, so the matrix form will not be square.

Comment: That is fine. My aim is not to have the matrix and then multiply by the signal to get the STFT. My aim is just to obtain a matrix of basis vectors of STFT. Any hints for that?